# just show not repeated value

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table

| id | c_id | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3444 | 34 | 3377752 |
| 3446 | 35 | 3473747 |
| 3447 | 35 | 3532061 |
| 3454 | 37 | 3379243 |
| 3455 | 38 | 3464467 |
| 3456 | 38 | 3377493 |

I want to create a table which is show me not repeated value in a c_id column (repeat just 1 time). the result should be:

| id | c_id | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3444 | 34 | 3377752 |
| 3454 | 37 | 3379243 |

```
GROUP BY  c_id, number
HAVING COUNT(cart_id) = 1
```

i tried this but it shows me repeated value again

Comment: Group only by c_id

Answer (score 4):

```sql
SELECT ANY_VALUE(id) id,
       c_id,
       ANY_VALUE(`number`) `number`
FROM tablename
GROUP BY c_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Comment: @ysth What's the difference which row should ANY_VALUE take data from if there is ONLY ONE row?

Comment: @Akina nice trick using ANY_VALUE. +1

Comment: sorry, you are correct.

Comment: @ErgestBasha In this particular case we can use MIN or MAX - this does not effect the output.

Comment: @Akina The idea to use ANY_VALUE is nice, but I think there is no real advantage of this here? Or if there is one, it would be nice if you point it out in your answer. Otherwise, just use MIN has the advantage it's Standard-SQL and will do on each DBMS.

Comment: @JonasMetzler ANY_VALUE is more fast than MIN/MAX - in general. But in this particular case the difference should be non-detectable, I think. And in addition - ANY_VALUE not guarantees but provides the values to be extracted from the same (and indefinite) row.

Comment: Ok, so you proposed this because of performance? Thanks for adding this!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows :

```
select t.*
from _table t
  inner join (
    select c_id
    from _table
    group by c_id
    having count(1) = 1
) as s on s.c_id = t.c_id;
```

Check it here : https://dbfiddle.uk/RlxxQ_05